# react native: importing a file with dynamic filename

Tags: json, react-native, dynamic, import, require

In React Native:
I would like to import a file using require at runtime. 
e.g.
`let mydata = require('../data/' + new Date().getFullYear().toString() + '.json');`

Since I have more than a couple hundred json files it is not feasible to hard code all the files.
in angular you can just use the above code and it works, but I think RN requires a static path. I am hoping there is an alternative way to do it.
any help appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the problems i have encountered. As i have heard of, react's `require()`only uses static url not variables, that means that you have to do `require('/path/file')`. Here is my version of solution:

```
const images = {
    profile: {
        profile: require('./profile/profile.png'),
        comments: require('./profile/comments.png'),
    },
    image1: require('./image1.jpg'),
    image2: require('./image2.jpg'),
};
export default images;
```

not the best option, but you can get away with it sometimes.

Comment: thank you, but that solution is not going to work for me, coz i have hundreds of files and cannot hard code all into individual require statements